# How to do math operations in a single column in bash and/or using awk?

Tags: bash, math, awk

I have a column of several rows like this:

```
20.000
15.000
42.500
42.500
45.000
45.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
```

and I need to end up with a file where:

first element is 20/2

second element is the previous value + 15/2

third element is the previous values + 42.5/2

an so on until the end

My problem is how to do the "loop".

Comment: this is *running total* aka *rolling sum* by two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply,

```
$ awk '{print v+=$1/2}' file

10
17.5
38.75
60
82.5
105
130
155
180
205
230
255
280
305
330
```

you can set `printf` formatting if needed

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'print $s += $_ / 2' input-file > output-file
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-n` reads the input line by line, executing the code for each
- `$_` is the value read from each line
- `/ 2` is division by 2
- `+=` is the operator that adds its ride hand side to its left hand side and stores the result in the left hand side, returning the new value. I named the variable `$s` as in "sum".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '{prev += ($0) / 2; printf("%.3f\n", prev);}' a2.txt
```

Input:

```
20.000
15.000
42.500
42.500
45.000
45.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
50.000
```

Output:

```
10.000
17.500
38.750
60.000
82.500
105.000
130.000
155.000
180.000
205.000
230.000
255.000
280.000
305.000
330.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need output to be one line:

```
awk '{s+=$1/2; out = out s " ";} END{print out}' file
#=> 10 17.5 38.75 60 82.5 105 130 155 180 205 230 255 280 305 330
```

There's an extra space at the end which I think has no harm.
You can remove it if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might looking for `for` loop

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print  temp = temp + $i/2  }' filename
```

remember one thing, ***i*** refers to a column number if you want to run this operation in only one column you can change value of

*i = column number; i <= column number;*

You can use this loop for complex scenario.

If you want to change the separator you can use parameter like -F and the separator.

```
awk -F ":" '{}' filename
```

[image]